# MS Excel 2013 - finding and replacing data

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have business task and I really don´t know how to deal with it. I have table of data e.g.

```
A      B   C    D   Result
2021 5044 NEMR 5038 ?????
```

and I need to put into cell "result" this: find value of cell D e.g.(5038) in column B and replace it with data from column A on the same line. So if it will be found on line B44 replace it with data from A44. Data in column B are unique and in column A too.

I tried replace, find but probably there will need to be some multi task.

Comment: The data above should appear in table sorry for bad format.

Comment: The question is pretty ambiguous because it isn't clear how the line of data in the example relates to the rows you mention.  This would be easier to understand if your example includes a number of (labeled) rows of data, and you refer to that to explain how to get to the results you want.

Comment: Try reading about [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) - I think this is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: not clear at all what your asking here.  It would be easier if you included a "before" and "after" example to show what you want to achieve.  It appears that English is your second language so I don't want to be too critical, but this might be the easiest way to get your point across :)

Comment: This is simple table with 4 columns and 2 rows.
2021 5277 R.NEMR          5638//////////
2332 5638 R.CHRUD        5277

This is how result shoud look like:
2021 5277 R.NEMR          5638 2332/////////
2332 5638 R.CHRUD        5277 2021

Comment: graphic of this form doesn´t allow to put in better format sorry for that. So we can distinguish the columns like A,B,C,D and (E) and Rows like 1,2. The result is that when I search for number 5638 in the whole column B then is shows some result but for me I need result from cell A just on the same line.

Comment: when I put this formula - =VLOOKUP(D2,A2:B400,1,FALSE) it shows me error on the screen. Is there probability that 2013 doesn´t know this formula?

Comment: @Domorodec You get the error because `VLOOKUP` assumes the value you want is in the first column of the range you give it, `A2:B400` in this case. Since you want to search in the second column and return the value from the first column, `VLOOKUP` won't work. Try the `INDEX`/`MATCH` combination suggested by [Tim Wilkinson](http://superuser.com/a/1158501/348859). You could reverse columns `A` & `B` but there are [other reasons](http://www.mbaexcel.com/excel/why-index-match-is-better-than-vlookup/) why `INDEX`/`MATCH` is better than `VLOOKUP`.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to look up a value in column B and return the corresponding value in column A? Use `INDEX MATCH`.

```
=INDEX(A:A, MATCH(D2,B:B, 0))
```

Comment: Hi I have partly resolved this issue by using my langue expression cause I have figured out that if I have MS office in differnet language then commands in english doesn´t work- this is what works for 90% - =SVYHLEDAT(C2;A$2:B$255;2;NEPRAVDA) and also switching columns. But there is only one problem. Not each cell is filled with number but with error. Check this out.

Comment: result 1 - 2304
result 2 - 2069
result 3 - #NENÍ_K_DISPOZICI
result 4 - 2309

Comment: I know that it is hard to advice not having any sample data sheet but I have checked all data and they are the same so I really don´t understand why one or most of cells are ok with correct result but some not.

Comment: RESOLVED - all works good with formule I put above :-) - Thanks all for their help.

Answer (score -1):

```
SVYHLEDAT(C2;A$2:B$255;2;NEPRAVDA)
```

and also switching columns

Comment: Welcome to Super User! While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.